# How to delete rows in Android SQLite table where date is prior to a specified date (where date is in the format MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android SQLite table and need to delete rows from the table where the date is prior to 05/01/2019.  I know this is simple if the format is YYYY/MM/DD however the format is this MM/DD/YYYY.

The db contains this data:
"05/03/2019"
"05/03/2019"
"01/15/2020"
"06/15/2020"

When I do this:

```
String whereClause=" created_date <= '05/01/2019'";
getContext().getContentResolver().delete(MyTable.CONTENT_URI, whereClause, null);
```

It will delete the row that contains: "01/15/2020, because, 01/15/2020 is less than 05/01/2019.

I'm making the assumption that I'll need to fetch all rows then iterate through them and convert the MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/DD/MM, then delete based on the date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the string value inline to make it ordered, i.e. refactor the string value from format `MM/DD/YYYY` to format `YYYY/MM/DD` using `substr()` and `||` string concatenation:

```
String whereClause = " substr(created_date,7,4) || '/' || substr(created_date,1,5) <= '2019/05/01'";
```

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is better because then you can use them with the built in date and time functions.

Comment: @Shawn Sure, but is unnecessary for this case, and would require 3 `substr()` calls, so this is simpler, for this case.